# Accessing Cookies of Other Domains using JavaScript/Java

Tags: java, javascript, html, cookies, session-cookies

I am developing a Analytics Software and there is a need to fetch or read User Behaviour from competitor websites. I am thinking that accessing the information from cookies of the competitor site would be a better option. Is there any alternative to this. Also, How to access cookies from all domains using either JavaScript or Java.

Comment: I do not think you can do this, especially in java

Comment: Yes Rugal, I also thought that it is not possible using Java, so I am looking for an alternative.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If this would have been possible the e-commerce world would have been different. It was possible in early browsers but in modern browsers you cannot access cookies from other domains .

Comment: Thanks for the reply Vineet. Do you know any other alternative to track behaviour of the user whom we track on the competitor website.

Comment: Hi Jeevan sorry to say but you cannot track others website without prior permission...there is something called robots.txt which gives you permission to scrap others website . And your competitor will never include you in robots.txt :)

Comment: Thank you so much Vineet. I shall have to look for any other alternative then.

Comment: @VineetKasat Robots.txt has nothing to do with tracking users on websites not owned by you. It is meant as an advisory for web crawlers to access or not access certain pages on your website, but is not enforced in any way. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robots_exclusion_standard#Disadvantages

Answer (score 2):

And if this is possible it is a security risk too, because typically information regarding sessions on a website will be stored in a cookie. If you are able to read cookies on other domains that is a security breach.

Comment: Yes, I do agree. But I beleive all e-commerce sites some how track our behaviour and I just wanted to find, how they could achieve it.

Comment: For example, you shopped something on xyz.com and xyz.com stored some information regarding what you have seen on their site in a cookie. Now some other site has an embedded iframe loading xyz.com advertisements. When the iframe of xyz.com is loaded, the cookie stored by xyz.com when you visited their website will also be passed. With the help of that cookie the relevant ad will be loaded from xyz.com. This is one of the ways. But i seriously doubt the cookie of xyz.com read by some abc.com directly without iframe.

Comment: Thanks Siva Krishna Gontla. I have played with iframes to read cookies from other domains with no success. This option too seems to be not viable for me.

Comment: @SivaKrishnaGontla Inside that iframe if cookies are passed. Is there any way in which I can write a script tag there and email the cookie to myself. (using document.cookie option) ?